# Merge three regex groups

Tags: java, regex

I have three different sentences which contains repetetive parts.
I want to merge three different regex groups in one, and then replace all mathes to white space.
I am asking you for help, how should I megre these groups ?

```
String locked = "LOCKED (center)"; //LOCKED() - always the same part
String idle = "Idle (second)"; // Idle() - always the same part
String OK = "example-OK"; // -OK - always the same part
```

I've built three regular expressions, but they are split. How should i megre them ?

```
String forLocked = locked.replaceAll("^LOCKED\\s\\((.*)\\)", "$1");
String forIdle = idle.replaceAll("^Idle\\s\\((.*)\\)", "$1");
String forOK = OK.replaceAll("(.*)\\-OK", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this technically works, but it doesn't "feel great."

```
private static final String REGEX =
    "^((Idle|LOCKED) *)?\\(?([a-z]+)\\)?(-OK)?$";

... your code ...

System.out.println(locked.replaceAll(REGEX, "$3"));
System.out.println(idle.replaceAll(REGEX, "$3"));
System.out.println(OK.replaceAll(REGEX, "$3"));
```

Output is:

```
center
second
example
```

Breaking down the expression:

1. `^((Idle|LOCKED) *)?` - Possibly starts with Idle or Locked followed by zero or more spaces
2. `\\(?([a-z]+)\\)?` - Has a sequence of lowercase characters possible embedded inside optional parentheses (also, we want to match that sequence)
3. `(-OK)?$` - Possibly ends with the literal `-OK`.

There are still some issues though. The optional parentheses aren't in any way tied together, for example. Also, this would give false positives for compounds like `Idle (second)-OK` --> `second`.

I had a more stringent regex at first, but one of the additional challenges is to keep a consistent match index on the group you want to replace with (here, `$3`.) In other words, there's a whole set of regex where if you could use, say `$k` and `$j` in different situations, it would be easier. But, that goes against the whole point of having a single regex to begin with (if you need some pre-existing knowledge of the input you're about to match.) Better would be to assume that we know nothing about what is inside the identifiers `locked`, `idle`, and `OK`.

Comment: Thank you for such saturated answer

Comment: Can I ask you one more quastion please? How can I deal with case sensetive when user types: -oK -OK -Ok -ok. How can i ignore the case ?

Comment: Why am I getting error doing this: (?i)([A-Za-z0-9ÆæÅåØø&\s]+)(-OK)$  web-page for test: http://www.regexr.com

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried this in java IDE and seems like its working. Probably it's a web-page syntax issue.

Comment: Hey Andrew, you probably want to adapt `[a-z]` to handle a broader range of characters. `[a-zA-Z]` for example. Just don't include `\\(` or `\\-` or `\\)` because it might break other assumptions in the overall regex. Also keep in mind that a Java regex won't work in other languages since it uses double backslashes, which is "unusual."

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them with `|` like this:

```
String regex = "^LOCKED\\s\\((.*)\\)|^Idle\\s\\((.*)\\)|(.*)\\-OK$";

String forLocked = locked.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
String forIdle = idle.replaceAll(regex, "$2");
String forOK = OK.replaceAll(regex, "$3");
```